How to ensure use of an index?
I have the following query:
SELECT cp.ID_Case
FROM dbo.CaseParty cp (NOLOCK)
JOIN dbo.Client cli (NOLOCK) ON CASE
     WHEN cli.ClientType = 'atty' AND cp.ID_ClientAttorney = cli.ID_Client THEN 1
     WHEN cli.ClientType = 'adj' AND cp.ID_ClientAdjuster = cli.ID_Client THEN 1
     ELSE 0
     END = 1
WHERE cli.ID_Client = @ID_Client

When I run it, the execution plan does a clustered index scan on the primary key index for table CaseParty.  There are about 700k rows in that table, so the query takes a significant amount of time.  I acknowledge that the join, requiring a CASE expression, is less than ideal, but that is what I have to work with.
I've tried creating all sorts of indexes, but it just won't use them:
CREATE INDEX IX_CaseParty_ClientAttorneyAdjuster ON dbo.CaseParty (ID_ClientAttorney, ID_ClientAdjuster);
CREATE INDEX IX_CaseParty_ClientAttorney ON dbo.CaseParty (ID_ClientAttorney);
CREATE INDEX IX_CaseParty_ClientAdjuster ON dbo.CaseParty (ID_ClientAdjuster);

I've also tried changing the CASE join to OR (example below) but it changes nothing.
SELECT cp.ID_Case
FROM dbo.CaseParty cp (NOLOCK)
JOIN dbo.Client cli (NOLOCK) 
    ON (cli.ClientType = 'atty' AND cp.ID_ClientAttorney = cli.ID_Client)
    OR (cli.ClientType = 'adj' AND cp.ID_ClientAdjuster = cli.ID_Client)
WHERE cli.ID_Client = @ID_Client

What am I doing wrong?

Just an idea. May be you can try to split this query into two united by UNION ALL ?

Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere - it is not recommended to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Have you tried an index hint?   FROM dbo.CaseParty cp WITH (INDEX(CaseParty_ClientAttorneyAdjuster)

@BartMcEndree I did, but then it does an scan of the hinted index.

That expression don't seems to be sargable, so it'll not use the index, probably try simplyfing the ON clause to make it use the index. That the optimizere chose to ignore the index means that the index won't help the query.

Just make two joins on same table with each ID?

The seek on dbo.CaseParty needs to be either on the ID_ClientAttorney column or the ID_ClientAdjuster column depending on the ClientType value.
Assuming you have appropriate indexes for both these seeks then you could do
SELECT ISNULL(cp1.ID_Case, cp2.ID_Case) AS ID_Case
FROM   dbo.Client cli
       LEFT JOIN dbo.CaseParty cp1
              ON cp1.ID_ClientAttorney = cli.ID_Client
                 AND cli.ClientType = 'atty'
       LEFT JOIN dbo.CaseParty cp2
              ON cp2.ID_ClientAdjuster = cli.ID_Client
                 AND cli.ClientType = 'adj'
WHERE  cli.ID_Client = @ID_Client
       AND ( cp1.ID_ClientAttorney IS NOT NULL
              OR cp2.ID_ClientAdjuster IS NOT NULL ) 

Or
SELECT cp.ID_Case
FROM   dbo.Client cli
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT cp1.ID_Case
                    FROM   dbo.CaseParty cp1
                    WHERE  cp1.ID_ClientAttorney = cli.ID_Client
                           AND cli.ClientType = 'atty'
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT cp2.ID_Case
                    FROM   dbo.CaseParty cp2
                    WHERE  cp2.ID_ClientAdjuster = cli.ID_Client
                           AND cli.ClientType = 'adj') cp
WHERE  cli.ID_Client = @ID_Client 

